# Last Message Sent by User Messenger Bot

Tags: facebook-messenger

I'm working with Facebook Messenger Bots and I need a way to make an HTTP Request for the last message sent by the user. All I can find is that Messenger Bots send a web hook with the information but, I specifically need to be able to manually check for the last message sent by the user. Any input would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You'll likely need to handle the webhook and save the data yourself.

Comment: More importantly what have you tried so far, what specific error are you getting?  As it is your question seems like you want us to tell you how to write an entire application.

Comment: Hi. I was afraid of that. I haven't tried much yet. Just looking to see if there's an API to use that could check for the last message sent.

Comment: Its not possible, save received messages on your end and use that data for checking last message when needed.